# Removing special symbols in from python string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to remove all kinds of special symbols from each word in the given string `sen` but I'm not able to figure a method in python to properly achieve it.

```
import string
def LongestWord(sen): 

    maxlen = 0
    count = 0
    words = sen.split()
    for word in words:
        ''.join(e for e in word if e.isalnum())
        if maxlen < len(word):
            maxlen = len(word)
            sen = words[count]
        count = count +1
    return sen

    # keep this function call here  
    print LongestWord(raw_input())
```

For the following string : 
"a beautiful sentence^&!"

I get this as the output : sentence^&!

Please help in figuring out how to remove this special symbols and punctuation marks.

Comment: What do you mean by "special symbols"? Punctuation?

Comment: please properly indent your code

Comment: You are not saving the `''.join(...)` part in any variable.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar thanks for the help... I thought `''.join(...)` would automatically store the result in word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Python String join() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm).

> This method returns a string, which is the concatenation of the strings in the sequence seq. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

In short, you need to save what it returns in a variable.

```
def LongestWord(sen):
    words = sen.split()
    answer_string = ''
    for word in words:
        answer_string += ''.join(e for e in word if e.isalnum())
    return answer_string

print(LongestWord("a beautiful sentence^&!"))
```

Output:

```
abeautifulsentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to store result of the `''.join(...)` in a variable

```
word = ''.join(e for e in word if e.isalnum())
```